# how to push db values to array - MEAN stack

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mean-stack, nodemailer

Am trying to create email app with MEAN stack. from the list i just want to send same mail to selected(checkbox using here to select) contact from list of contacts.For mail am using node mailer.

see below code

html.html

```
 <tr class='danger'>
                        <td>Name</td>
                        <td>Email</td>
                        <td>Number</td>
                        <td>Edit</td>
                        <td>Delete</td>
                        <td>Select All
                            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="selectedAll" ng-click="selectAll()" class="pull-right" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>

    <td>
                            <input type="checkbox" class="pull-right" ng-model="person.Selected" ng-click="checkIfAllSelected()" />
                        </td>
```

myModl.js

```
  angular.module('mailContacts', ['ui.bootstrap']);
  var modalControl = function($scope, $modal, $log) {
      var key = 1000;
      $scope.items = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3'];
      $scope.open = function(person) {
          var modalInstance = $modal.open({
              templateUrl: 'e.html',
              controller: itemCtrl,
              resolve: {
                  items: function() {
                      return $scope.persons;
                  },
                  key: function() {
                      return key;
                  }
              }
          });
          modalInstance.result.then(function(selectedItem) {
              $scope.selected = selectedItem;
          }, function() {});
      };
  };
```

listController.js

```
     //getting all contacts in list
        var onAddressGetCompleted = function(response){
            $scope.addresses = response.data;
            console.log($scope.addresses);
        }
          //select and deselect items in list
                    $scope.selectAll = function() {
                        angular.forEach($scope.persons, function(person) {
                            person.Selected = $scope.selectedAll;
                        });
                    };
                    $scope.checkIfAllSelected = function() {
                        $scope.selectedAll = $scope.persons.every(function(person) {
                            return person.Selected == true
                        })
                    };

server.js

    app.get('/persons', function(req, res) {
        console.log('Received find all persons request');
        db.Persons.find(function(err, docs) {
            console.log(docs);
            res.json(docs);
        })
    });

    app.get('/person/:id', function(req, res) {
        console.log('Received findOne person request');
        db.Persons.findOne({ _id: new mongojs.ObjectId(req.params.id) }, function(err, docs) {
            console.log(docs);
            res.json(docs);
        })
    });
```

kindly tell me how to send email to selected contacts

helps much appreciated.

Comment: Hi! Could you please post all of your html document? Are you setting ng-app andd ng-controller in it?

Comment: @LuizEduardodeChristo kindly share your email id so that i can send my file.. there's lots of codes to post

Comment: You can put it here: https://jsfiddle.net/dudu84/zrjjvh8L/
It will be easier!

Comment: but sir, i really don't know how to add my local files in fiddle. am searching CDNs for "nodemailer-smtp-transport, nodemailer, email-existence".but there's nothing exist. how can add node packages in fiddle.                                                                                                   and below the link is what i need exactly.  https://www.sitepoint.com/mastering-your-inbox-with-gmail-javascript-api/  but it throws me error eventhough having valid gamil "Token and secret key"

Comment: @LuizEduardodeChristo sir. now check the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/zrjjvh8L/1/ . i just put some code which got from this https://github.com/sitepoint-editors/gmail-api-javascript-example